# shifting a list to the right in python

Tags: python, arrays

There are several other questions with nearly the same title, please read the full question.
I'm trying to shift a list in python to the right, and then modifying `array[0]`, however doing this results in modifying both `array[0]` and `array[1]`:

```py
arr = [[91, 3], [90, 3], [89, 3], [88, 3], [87, 3]]

pairs = enumerate
def shiftArray(a):
    o = a[0]
    for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
        a[i] = a[i-1]
    a[0] = o
    return a
shiftArray(arr)
arr[0][0] += 1
print(arr) # [[92, 3], [92, 3], [90, 3], [89, 3], [88, 3]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem is that `a[0]` and `a[1]` are **the same list object**. Please see the linked duplicates to understand how to avoid the problem, by creating a separate list with the same value.

Comment: What does your desired output look like?